# What does the Markdown > Preview: Open Markdown Links setting in VS Code do?

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-code

What does the following setting in VS Code do?

[image: Markdown > Preview: Open Markdown Links setting]

I've tried both choices (inPreview and inEditor) and I can't find any difference in the way links are opened.  This includes clicking links in the editor and in the preview tab.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This affects paths to other markdown files like `[CHANGELOG](./CHANGELOG.md)`.

[image: readme + preview]

With `inPreview`, the CHANGELOG link will switch to a preview of CHANGELOG.md.

[image]

With `inEditor`, it will open the CHANGELOG.md file.

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming.  I suspected that this was what it was meant to do, but VS Code does not behave for me the way you describe.  I was curious if perhaps it was a bug, and this seems to confirm that suspicion.